# SDL Tridion Vs Drupal as CMS

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9, sdl-cloud

Can someone lay out a few key differences between Drupal and Tridion? And possible reasons to stick with Tridion? Currently we are using SDL Tridion and assessing to move to Drupal.

Answer (score 6):

Comparing the platforms features by features will not truly help to assess which platform is best suited for your company's project. What is more important is to list all your key requirements, KPIs, current challenges with Tridion and with your specific implementation of it, your corporate roadmap with detailed criteria and priorities or weighting system and then ask the vendors to answer specifically to those. This will give you a solid approach to understand which vendor is most suited to your requirements, goals and organizational structure.

**Please contact me** or your SDL sales representative to discuss the inherent reasons why you are now looking at Drupal and how SDL Tridion can work better for you in the future by taking a deeper look at your challenges and opportunities of improvement of your Tridion implementation.
I am reachable at pconil(at)sdl(dot)com

Thank you